# Accessing superclass properties from subclass

Tags: objective-c

I'm running into some trouble implementing a simple super/sub class scheme. I declare an NSMutableDictionary in the superclass, and am trying to access it in a subclass, but it only returns null. Any help would be appreciated.

```
@interface RootModel : NSObject <Updatable, TouchDelegate>
@property (nonatomic) NSMutableDictionary *gameValues;
@end

@interface SubclassModel : RootModel
@end

@implementation RootModel

- (id)initWithController:(id)controller {
    if ((self = [super init])) {
        _controller = controller;

        _gameValues = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                       [NSNumber numberWithFloat:300.0f], KEY_JUMP_VELOCITY,
                       [NSNumber numberWithFloat:49.47f], KEY_GRAVITY,
                       [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.25f], KEY_JUMP_TIME_LIMIT,
                       nil];

        NSLog(@"%@", _gameValues);

    }
    return self;
}

@implementation SubclassModel

- (id)init{
    if ((self = [super init])) {
        // This NSLog prints "(null)" if using super.gameValues or self.gameValues, why?
        NSLog(@"subclass: %@", super.gameValues);

    }
    return self;
}
@end
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Refer this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5588799/objective-c-how-do-you-access-parent-properties-from-subclasses) for descrption and detail, as will remove that NSObject from the first line of your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Catfish_Man answered, your `init` method needs to call `[super initWithController:]`. However you seem to show a misunderstanding of the class/super class inheritance model with your comment:

> My superclass is initialized by another controller class. Any calls to the super's properties (which were initialized in initWithController:) are valid (they return values, not null).

When you create an instance of your `SubclassModel` then that instance has as *part of itself* a `RootModel` instance. That `RootModel` instance is *not* shared with any other instance of `SubclassModel` or `RootModel`.

So if "another controller class" creates and initialises and instance of `RootModel`, which in turn displays your `NSLog` output, then that is a totally different object to your `SubclassModel` instance - and the `RootModel` that is part of your `SubclassModel` instance is not initialised, as you don't call `[super initWithController:]`, hence you `NSLog` in `SubclassModel` shows `nil`.

Comment: So it would be a better idea to have a singleton RootModel, so each superclass does not init its own version of the model?

Comment: @Clever - No. A singleton is a different concept. When you declare a subclass, say `B`, of a class `A`, then *every* instance of `B` has its *own* `A`. That is the inheritance model. If you are unsure about this you need to read up on how subclass inheritance works, this model is fundamental to Obj-C (and most OO languages) and you need to understand it.

Comment: Thanks for the reminder. Apparently it's been too long. However, now that you have clarified this– I absolutely do not want every subclass to have it's own A.

Comment: @Clever - in that case `SubclassModel` should not be a subclass of `RootModel` at all; instead it should maintain a reference (in an instace variable) to a shared model and its initialisation method would be something like `- (id) initWithSharedRootModel:(RootModel *)sharedRootModel`. *(It looks like you might be trying to follow a delagation-based rather than inheritance-based model, if so you must implement it yourself as Obj-C is inheritance based. If this makes no sense, just ignore!)*

Answer (score 1):

Your subclass `init` method needs to call `[super initWithController:]`, since that's where the actual initialization happens.

(or the superclass `initWithController:` needs to call `[self init]`, and you need to move the initialization work you're relying on to `init`)

Comment: Are you sure? My superclass is initialized by another controller class. Any calls to the super's properties (which were initialized in `initWithController:`) are valid (they return values, not null).

Comment: Based on the code posted, yes, quite sure. Set a breakpoint where gameValues is initialized and see if it's hit. Unless there's something you didn't include, it won't be.

Comment: Imagine that some other class calls initWithController (which it does). Setting a break point @ gameValues does as expected... they are assigned and hold a value.

Comment: Unless you're calling more than one init method on the same object (which is bad! Don't do that!), then your breakpoint hit a call on some other object. Make sure that the address of 'self' when that breakpoint is hit is the same as the address of 'self' in the non-working subclass.