# How to implement like JAVA ‘Protect’ function in Object-C?

Tags: objective-c, ios

How to implement like JAVA ‘Protect’ function in Object-C?I wanna access father class method in subclass,but i don`t konw how to implement it use Ojbect-C.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the answer of your question here:

[What is the Objective-C equivalent of a public get/protected set property in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1338434/what-is-the-objective-c-equivalent-of-a-public-get-protected-set-property-in-c-s)

Or here:

[Objective-C - Private vs Protected vs Public](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4869935/objective-c-private-vs-protected-vs-public)

I hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can just call

```
[super myMethod];
```

to access the parent method

Comment: But I only can access public method use that. I want access parent method that can`t be access by other method.

Comment: You need to be clearer, I don't understand what you are trying to access